# Get yesterday date in php using existing date variable

Tags: php, date

I have a date code below:

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

My question is how will I get the yesterday time of `2011-01-01 15:00:00`. I am currently use this `date('Ymd',strtotime("-1 days"))` but I think it's not right. What is the best way to get the yesterday date using my first code?

Comment: `$date->modify("-1 day")`

Answer (score 4):

There are tons of answers to this question in the internet and on stackoverflow as well. So, once again:

Use ::modify() method on DateTime: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```
$date->modify('-24 hours')
$date->modify('-1 day')
```

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\n";
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$date->sub($interval); 
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`\DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) function:-

```
$date->modify('-1 day');
```

Or you could subtract a [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval):-

```
$date->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D');
```

See the [DateTime manual](http://php.net/datetime) for more information.

If you don't want the original $date variable to be modified then you could use [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/DateTimeImmutable) instead:-

```
$date = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$yesterday = $date->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use modify function

```
<?php
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo "\n";
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

check here : https://eval.in/586553

For more info check this : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php